# Can't see SQLite database changes on a database open by multiple processes

Tags: sqlite

I have a process that opens a database using sqlite3_open and sets journal mode to WAL.

Another process, uses sqlite3_open to open that same database.  Everything seems to work, but the problem is that second process does not seem to see changes made by the first process.   I am trying to fetch count, or rowids, and they stay the same.

I am sure that database is being updated, because refreshing using SQLiteDatabaseBrowser shows the changes.

I tried multiple ways of opening databases, and multiple ways of querying, but no luck so far.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a network file system, or a virtual machine?

Comment: Maybe your answer is here? https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5 .In any case I think sqlite is not the most suitable when accessing and entering data from different processes.

Comment: @CL - I am running on a Hyper V VM, did not realize this might matter.

Comment: @VictorGGl - Only one process is writing the data, the other one is reading.

Comment: Are both processes running in the same VM?

Comment: @CL - yes, same VM.  Also, the SQLBrowser tool shows data on refresh, so in all honesty I suspect user error on my behalf.  But I am quite stuck as nothing I do made difference so far, so I thought I'd ask to see if I am missing something obvious related to sqlite/multiple processes/WAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was, and as usual in cases where thing make no sense, mistake on my side.  Problem is however subtle, so worth mentioning.

I was doing sqlite3_reset calls on cached prepared statements lazily, that is *before* I reuse the prepared statement, not immediately after I am done executing it.  Problem is that this pattern means that there’s always prepared statement pending reset.  Apparently, reset is necessary to be able to see updates to the database (probably some mutex is being held).

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: after sleeping on it this behavior actually makes sense.  Updates should not be visible during the time of prepared statement execution, otherwise it might never be done or accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are used to isolate connections from each other, especially to make changes visible only after a transaction has completed.

So for changes to be visible, the writing connection must end its transaction, and the reading connection must not have started its own transaction before that. (When using automatic transactions, ensure that statements are reset or finalized.)

Comment: You might be onto something here.  The way my writing process works is it begins transaction, and keeps it open for a while till time out expires or number of records reaches certain limit.  Then, transaction is ended, and new is started and the flow is repeated again.

The reader does not use transactions, so I assume auto transaction is started.  Are you saying that I cannot read database from the reading process while writer still has transaction open?  I thought, that contents of the previous commit should be visible.

Comment: The reader should see all changes done in transactions that were ended before its own started.

Comment: Is the database file stored inside the VM, or on a drive mapped from elsewhere?

Comment: The database is on the VM.  Both processes, writer and reader are running on that same VM.  It is not a mapped drive, part of VM .vhd I guess, but I am not deeply familiar with the workings of VM.  Might be relevant to mention, both writer and reader are multithreaded, and reader/writer thread might not necessarily be the same that opened connection. Thanks for bearing with me.